# OutOfMemoryException with StreamReader()

Tags: c#

I'm trying to Read through a bunch of Zipped Files without Opening them in Fileviewer cause of time consumption.  So errog I'm reading them in through a stream.  However for LARGE files like 10GB+ it's not able to read it and kills the thread.There has to be a way to fix this and make it so that regardless of file size it'll read them.  Please help.
The following is getting a `OutOfMemoryException` around the StreamReader Portion of this
code.

```
    using(FileStream zipToOpen - new FileStream(fileLocation + "\\" + zipfile + ".zip":, FileMOde.open)){
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Read)){
        int index = 0;
        List<Tuple<string, int, int>> reportFiles = new List<Tuple<string, int, int>>();
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries){
            int tranTypeTranSet = 0;
            int tranTypeTrans = 0;
            while (index <archive.Entries.Count()){
                if(archive.Entries[index].FullName.Startswith("asdf"){
                    bacgroundWorker.ReportProgress(index, archive.Entries.Count);
                    ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.Entreis[index];
                    using(streamReader reader = new StreamReader(archive.Entries[index].Open())){
                        while(!reader.EndOfStream){
                            string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            int fileTranSet = Regex.Matches( contents, transsetString).count;
                            int filleTran = Regex.Matches(contents, transstring).count;
                            tranTypeTranSet += fileTranSet;
                            tranTypeTrans += fileTran;
                            ReportFiles.Add(new Tuple<string, int, int>(archive.Entries[index].FullName,fileTransset, fileTran));
                            totalTypeTrans = tranTypeTrans;
                            totalTyupeTranSet = tranTypeTranSet;
                            reader.close();
                        }
                        index++;
                    }
                    zipToOpen.Close();
                }
                Directory.CreateDirectory(baseReportDirectoryLocation);
                createPreoprts(ReportType, reportFiles, totoalTypeTranset, totalTypeTrans);
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Here's the StackTrace

```
System.outOfMemoryException
HResult=0x80070000E
Message=Insufficent memory to continue the execution of the program
source = mscorlib
stackTrace:
at System.Text.StringBuilder.ExpandByABlock(int32 minBlockCharCount)
at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char* value, int32 valueCount)
at System.Text.StringBuilder.Appe4nd(Char[] value, int32 startIndex, Int32 charCount)
at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
at TransactionCounts.Form1.OnGenerate() in ______.cs:Line162
at TransactionCounts.Form1.Backgroundworker1_DoWork(Object sender,m DoWorkEventArgs e) in Form1.cs:line 285
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.ondowork(doworkeventargs e)
at System.componentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

Comment: You're going to have to read each file in chunks, so you can't use `ReadToEnd()`. How are the file contents structured?

Comment: The issue you are facing is probably due to consuming too much memory by reading the entire contents of the file into memory at once. Instead, read the file in chunks using a buffer and process each chunk individually.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel they're Simple Data Files with repeating Records in them.  So just Plain Text Files with New Lines.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton ok...how would you recommend doing that in a expediant way?

Comment: SO turns out it's actually the String for CONTENTS which is only allowed 2GB....and since some of the files are MASSIVELY Larger then that....ergo the issue.  SO now i'm trying to create a List<String> and reading each line...to make it so that it's adaptive....I may add a file size check to see if it's needed...will let you guys know... if an once I have an answer...unless someone posts first.

Answer (score 0):

As @EtiennedeMartel and @GrumpyCrouton have already mentioned you should not try to read huge files into memory because it never ends well.  It looks like your ultimate goal is to search the files using regular expressions.  So you need a way to partition the file into smaller chunks, perform regex on the chunks, and then join the results back together.  You can use the [Gigantor](https://github.com/imagibee/Gigantor) class library for this by replacing your inner while loop with something like the following...

```cs
using Imagibee.Gigantor
...

    // Create a synchronization event
    AutoResetEvent progress = new(false);

    // Create the Regex instances
    Regex transSetRegex = new(transsetString, RegexOptions.Compiled);
    Regex transRegex = new(transstring, RegexOptions.Compiled);

    // Create the first searcher and start it
    RegexSearcher transSetSearcher = new(progress);
    transSetSearcher.Start(pathToTextFile, transSetRegex, 80);

    // Create the second searcher and start it
    RegexSearcher transSearcher = new(progress);
    transSearcher.Start(pathToTextFile, transRegex, 80);

    // Put both searchers in a list
    var mySearchers = new List<RegexSearcher>() { transSetSearcher, transSearcher };

    // Wait for both searchers to complete
    RegexSearcher.Wait(
        mySearchers,
        progress,
        (_) => { Console.Write('.') },
        1000);
    Console.Write('\n');

    // Now its finished, check for errors and do something with matches
    foreach (var searcher in mySearchers) {
        if (searcher.LastError.Length != 0) {
            throw new Exception(searcher.LastError);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"found {searcher.MatchCount} matches in {searcher.Path}";
        foreach (var matchData in searcher.GetMatchData()) {
            foreach (var match in matchData.Matches) {
                Console.WriteLine($"{match}");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit**
Gigantor recently added support for searching compressed files without decompressing them to disk.

Gigantor does not have a way to work with compressed files, but I can see how that is a need and have [filed this issue](https://github.com/imagibee/Gigantor/issues/18).  So you would need to decompress the file yourself for now or look at how Gigantor makes the sausage and roll your own.  I hope this helps.